# Precompiled headers in VisualStudio Cross Platform (Linux) project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cross-platform, precompiled-headers

In a *regular* VisualStudio project you can setup the precompiled header by going to **Configuration Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Precompiled Headers**.[image]

However, when dealing with a **Cross Platform** (Linux) project, the **Precompiled Header** option is missing.

[image]

Is there any way to configure the Precompiled Header?

Comment: PCH is a compiler feature, so are you sure that g++ supports it in the same way as cl.exe ?

Comment: Not in the same way, but... VisualStudio does support PCH nicely for Android projects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in VisualStudio 2022 there's still no easy way to add support for precompiled headers. But luckily I've stumbled upon on this interesting solution  provided by **GTANAdam** on his Github page: https://gist.github.com/GTANAdam/3703fd5cb70d9a22159f58443a129f8b

With some minor changes I've managed to make things work for my projects.

The `chmod +x precompile.sh` is needed, else you might get the error `bash: ./precompile.sh: Permission denied`
And instead of using the suggested `sh precompile.sh` I've ended up using `./precompile.sh`. Additionally the `precompile.sh` file now contains the header `#!/bin/bash` (instead of `#!/bin/sh`)

[image]

Sample of my `precompile.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

gch="PCH.hpp.gch"
header="PCH.hpp"

function compile
{
    echo "Generating precompiled header.."
    g++ -I../ -std=c++14 -c -x c++-header PCH.cpp -o PCH.hpp.gch 
}

if [[ -f $gch ]]; then # File exists
  if [[ $header -nt $gch ]]; then
    compile
  else 
    echo "Precompiled header already exists.."
  fi
else 
    compile
fi
```

Some things to note. If you're editing your bash script file on windows platform, note that on windows, at every new line of the script, the text editors might add CR LF instead of just LF, and Linux  bash might start dropping errors like: `: not foundsh: 2: precompile.sh:`